# Changing Date Format in Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I tried looking this one up online, but I guess I'm not sure how I should phrase the question without a full explanation.

I've got a webform with a search bar. When you enter in a search term, it queries a database and pulls information and populates a gridview. I'm using the following code:

```
 string find = "SELECT tblShipments.ShipmentID as [Shipment ID], tblShipmentsAssets.DateShip as [Date Shipped],  FROM tblShipments INNER JOIN(tblAssets INNER JOIN tblShipmentsAssets ON tblAssets.AssetID = tblShipmentsAssets.AssetIDFK) ON tblShipments.ShipmentID = tblShipmentsAssets.ShipmentIDFK where(AssetIDFK like '%' + @assetidfk + '%' )";

        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(find, con);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@assetidfk", OleDbType.Char).Value = TxtSearch.Text;

        con.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = comm;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "AssetIDFK");
        SearchGridView.DataSource = ds;
        SearchGridView.DataBind();
```

In the past, I've simply populated a gridview solely with aspx code using `<asp:SqlDataSource>` and there I was able to get at the columns that held dates withing the `<columns>` tag and add in a `DataFormatString="{0:d}"` to get the format I wanted:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" HorizontalAlign="Center">
         <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NextCal" HeaderText="Calibration Due"  DataFormatString="{0:d}" >  
            </asp:BoundField>

        </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT , [NextCal] FROM [tblAssets]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

With my C# method of populating the gridview, I have no `<Columns>` section to change the data format. I would then assume I need to do this in the code behind, however I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: try something like this or play around with the format that you are expecting 
`DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}" `

Comment: So this worked. New problem though: when I have a my date column called out in the <column> section, it adds a duplicate column with that data. One with the old format, and one with the new format.

Comment: why are you using this line to execute a Select Query, `comm.ExecuteNonQuery();` also use datatable to fill also make sure you're query is not pulling duplicates.. change it to select Distinct.. to test vs running it wihout the Distinct..

Comment: Solved it: I needed to set < AutoGenerateColumns="false"> and then manually call out each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what I was doing wrong:

By having `<AutoGenerateColumns ="true">`, my columns were (big surprise) being automatically generated and then me adding in columns under the  tag in .aspx was generating duplicate columns.

I changed it to `<AutoGenerateColumns ="false">`, manually entered my columns in under the  tag and used the `DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}"`to change the date format.

Sorry for the dumb question. Hopefully this will help someone avoid the same mistake..